# How can I redirect the browser when a button is clicked?

Tags: jquery

I want to pass a URL on click of a button so the browser can redirect to the URL.

url value = `/web/SMI6041001090/home?contId=186&contName=sa`

When a user clicks on the button it should redirect to this URL.

```
var url = document.<portlet:namespace />regForm.fwdURL.value;
alert('url -->'+url);

jQuery('.submit-button').click(function(){
    // Pass URL here.
});
```

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are asking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to pass URL on clik of the
>   button. so browser can redirect to
>   URL.

You mean this:

```
var url = document.<portlet:namespace />regForm.fwdURL.value;

jQuery('.submit-button').click(function(){
    document.location.href = 'http://yoursite.com' + url;
});
```

Comment: sAc, what's the difference between document.location and window.location?

Comment: @fearofawhackplanet: You can use either, `location` is property of `window/document` objects.

Comment: @fear: *document.location* was originally read-only in some browsers.  Because of this, *window.location* was always the preferred method of directing the browser to another location, but it doesn't matter so much these days.

Comment: thanks, sAC, this what I was looking for  accepting your answer.